# TYPO3 Fluidcontent: How to use FAL inside an object

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux, fedext

I'm trying to build a custom Content Element with Flux. It should consist of a repeatable container with a header, a description text, an image and a PDF to download.

When using f:flux.inline.fal I don't manage to get more than one image working.

Here's my code:

```
<flux:form.section name="formeln">
    <flux:form.object name="formel">
        <flux:field.input name="number" label="Produktnummer"/>
        <flux:field.input name="description" label="Beschreibung"/>
        <flux:field.file name="pdf" label="PDF" allowed="pdf"/>
        <flux:field.inline.fal name="image" label="Bild" multiple="TRUE" maxItems="1" collapseAll="TRUE"  />
    </flux:form.object>
</flux:form.section>
```

Is there a limitation when using FAL?

Comment: isnt there a contradiction betweeen maxitems=1 and multiple=true? I'm not familiar with flux yet, but I can't see your repeatable container above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its currently not possible to use `flux:field.inline.fal` inside objects.
See https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/478